# get стрелочной функцией в typescript

Tags: typescript

Не получается прикрутить стрелочную функцию к get свойству. Как это можно сделать? Я пробовал сделать так

```
get message = () => { return _message;}  //ошибка: statement expected
```

Comment: Насколько я помню геттер нужно обьявлять как метод класса, а не лямду: `get message() { return _message;} `

Comment: Так я объявлять умею. Т.е. стрелочной функцией это сделать невозможно? я правильно понял?

Comment: @docty, в данном случае идет нарушение синтаксиса, при определении геттера нельзя употреблять `=` между именем и телом функции. Однако сделать getter с помощью стрелочной функции можно в конструкторе применяя `Object.defineProperty` функцию.

Comment: В чем интерес делать getter стрелочной функцией, если внутри не используется `this`?

Comment: Понял, жаль. Спасибо за подсказку с defineProperty. Я конечно так делать не буду, но это интересно, буду знать, спасибо

Comment: Ну я делаю все стрелочными функциями, почему нет? Так всё везде выглядит одинаково. [Тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/213455/) даже пишут, что они повышают производительность.

Comment: @docty, со стрелочными функциями иногда бывают проблемы. Их нужно использовать там, где их нужно использовать :-)

Comment: Наверное нельзя спрашивать про эти проблемы в этом вопросе? Но у меня пока проблем не было)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89338/discussion-between-grundy-and-docty).